# A question on a proof of Lebesgue's number lemma

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to prove

**Lebesgue's number lemma:** If the metric space $(X,d)$ is compact and an open cover of $X$ is given, then there exists a number $\delta>0$ such that for every $x\in X$, the open ball $B(x;\delta)$ is contained in some member of the cover.

**My attempt:** If $X=\varnothing$, then the lemma is clearly true so we may assume that $X\neq\varnothing$. Let $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ a finite open cover of $X$ and set $U=U_1\cup\ldots \cup U_n$. First, Suppose that $\partial U\neq\varnothing$ (where $\partial U$ denotes the boundary of $U$) and consider the set
$$
D=\{d(x,y):x\in X,y\in \partial U\}.
$$
Since $\partial U\neq\varnothing$ and $X\neq\varnothing$, it follows that $D\neq\varnothing$, so $\delta=\mathrm{inf}(D)$ exists. I claim that $\delta>0$. Suppose otherwise that $\delta=0$. Therefore, for every positive integer $n$, there exist $x_n\in X$, $y_n\in\partial U$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<1/n$. Since the sequence $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ is in $X$ and $X$ is compact, there exist a convergence sub-sequence $(x_{n_1},x_{n_2},x_{n_3},\ldots)$. Let $x_0\in X$ be its limit.

Now, given any $\varepsilon>0$, choose $k_1$ such that
$d(x_{n_k},x_0)<\varepsilon/2$ for every $k_1\le k$. In addition, choose $k_2$ such that $1/n_{k_2}<\varepsilon/2$. Hence, if $k_0=\max\{k_1,k_2\}$, then
$$
d(y_{n_k},x_0)\le d(y_{n_k},x_{n_k})+d(x_{n_k},x_0)
<\frac{1}{n_k}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$
for every $k_0\le k$. Therefore, $(y_{n_1},y_{n_2},y_{n_3},\ldots)$ converges to $x_0$ also. But this sequence is in $\partial U$ and since $\partial U$ is closed, it follows that $x_0\in \partial U$. On the other hand, $U\cap \partial U=\varnothing$ since $U$ is open, so $x_0\notin U$. But that is impossible since $U$ covers $X$. Thus $\delta>0$.

Now, given $x\in X$, there exist $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x;\epsilon)\subseteq U_i$ for some $i$. But $\epsilon\le \delta$, so the ball $B(x;\delta)$ is contained in $U_i$, as required.

My questions are:

(a) is this proof correct?

(b) How to prove the lemma in the case where $\partial U=\varnothing$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Here are some problems: If the $U_i$ cover X, then U is X and the boundary ist the closure of U (which is X) minus the interior (which is also X) hence empty for sure. Sets which are both open and closed do not have boundary, contrary to your intuition. Second problem: You need to consider infinite covers. The statement says that their is some $\delta$ which works for all sets of an infinite cover at ones.

Comment: Here is a hint: Suppose the lemma is false for some infinite cover and compact space. Can you construct a sequence with no cluster point/accumulation point (I don t know the right English word) ?

Comment: @Nico Due to compactness, you can reduce an infinite cover to a finite one.   If you can fit a minimum $\delta$ ball around each $x$ inside the finite ones,  then the lemma holds

Comment: @Alan You are right.

Comment: I agree with the first statement that @Nico made in his comment which is the boundary of U is empty for sure. For the proof, you can find it in the book Topology by Munkres (page 175), he had a nice proof for this lemma

Comment: Thanks. Can this proof be complicated for the case where U is clopen set? that, where the boundary is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof cannot work. Note that $\delta=0$ trivially whenever $\partial U \neq \emptyset$. Moreover it doesn't matter if we start with a finite cover or not. Even if we just have two clopen sets in the cover (e.g. as in the cover $(\leftarrow, \sqrt{2}), (\sqrt{2}, \rightarrow)$ of $\Bbb Q$), for any $\delta>0$ we have points in these two cover sets that are $< \delta$ apart, so this $\delta$ could not work as a Lebsgue number. We essentially need the compactness and so for any cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ we can pick $U_x \in \mathcal{U}$ and $r_x >0$ so that $B(x, 2r_x) \subseteq U_x$. Then take a finite subcover of the new open cover $\{B(x, r_x)\mid x \in X\}$ and apply compactness of $X$ to *that* to finish the proof in tehe right way.

Staying away from the boundary for the original cover won't work; it's not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer